# Can a Java applet request to run from the JRE of a JDK?

Tags: java, applet

Is it possible for a Java applet to run from the JRE of an installed JDK (as opposed to run from the standalone JRE)?

The rationale for the question is that Java applets [can request a given java version](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/index-141751.html#JAVA_VERSION) and I would like to understand if the only versions which are be checked for existence are the ones in standalone JREs, or if the ones in JDKs are checked (and used if they match) as well?

Background: for support / maintenance reasons developers need to keep specific JDKs of Java. Some of the versions are vulnerable to attacks and I want to assess whether they could be used unknowingly to the user. JREs are up to date but there are far more versions of JDKs than of JREs (which are kept at the last patch level of the version).

Comment: Suppose, this is impossible. Browser knows only about single version of JRE in which applet is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unfortunately possible, in practical terms. The existing Java versions are enabled / disabled in the Java configuration pane:

[image]

I just have one version here, but I could have several, including a vulnerable one. This vulnerable version could then in turn be called with `java_version`.